# Split long string into multiple lines regxp error

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I try to split a long string into multiple lines for output in react:

```
let text ='fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'
let rowEnd=10;
let regxp = new RegExp(rowEnd, "g");
let lines = text.match(regxp);
text = lines.join("\n");
console.log(text);
```

But getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the expected result should be that the string has been split after every 10th character into a new line.

Comment: why do you expect such result? have you checked regex syntax at least?

Comment: Yes. It's working if I dont create a variable for the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct `RegExp` which is `/.{10}/g`

```js
let text = "fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo";
let rowEnd = 10;
let regxp = new RegExp(`.{${rowEnd}}`, "g");
let lines = text.match(regxp);
text = lines.join("\n");
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another way is using `replace` method, like this :**

```js
let text ='0123456789abcsdbgdjb9876543210pol' ,
    rowEnd = 10 ,
    patt = new RegExp('.{' + rowEnd + '}','g') ;

console.log( text.replace(patt,'$&\n') ) ;
```